# Nuxt 3 useFetch reactivity/watch

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I don't really understand how Nuxt and its ways of fetching data and reactivity work.

I have a page with data retrieved from API using useFetch  and in the page I have input for updating that reactive data directly. On top of that I have @blur on the input that calls the PATCH api to update the value.

I am kind of confused why this PATCH api is called on every stroke when I am using useFetch. If I use useAsyncData with $fetch, It doesn not happen. Isn't that same?
Provided code example. So, why does PATCH api fires on every stroke (not on blur) if I use useFetch while useAsyncData works fine?

Provided code example below where PATCH useFetch is problematic but commented code works fine.

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const { data } = await useFetch<Project>(`/api/projects/${route.params.id}`);

// const { execute: update } = await useAsyncData(async () => {
//   await $fetch<Project>(`/api/projects/${route.params.id}`, {
//     method: "PATCH",
//     body: data.value,
//   });
// });
const { execute: update } = await useFetch(`/api/projects/${route.params.id}`, {
  method: "PATCH",
  body: data.value,
});
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="data" class="flex items-stretch px-6 py-4 h-[calc(100vh_-_66px)]">
    <textarea
      v-if="data.notes"
      v-model="data.notes"
      rows="5"
      class="textarea textarea-primary w-full resize-none"
      placeholder="Enter your notes"
      @blur="update()"
    ></textarea>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solution found.
`data.value` object is being watched for changes and it is being mutating with `v-model`.

Solution to the problem:

```html
const updateNotes = async () => {
  await $fetch(`/api/projects/${route.params.id}`, {
    method: "PATCH",
    body: data.value,
  });
};
```